# How to get specific user all versions of an object through dql?

Tags: version-control, version, dql

I want to get all versions of documents from dm_document

code I have written is

```
SELECT object_name, r_version_label FROM dm_sysobject where ( r_modifier='kishoren') and (r_object_id  in (select r_object_id from dm_sysobject where any r_version_label>='1.0'))
```

it is giving only current version labels
but I want out put like

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select r_object_id,i_chronicle_id,r_version_label from dm_sysobject(all) where i_chronicle_id='090008868006d5be' and owner_name='swathi'
```

This will give required output as above

Comment: ROW_BASED not ROWBASED is used when you want gave output as row based, not object based. Similar (or same) you already gained with using (all) after object type name